# How to append value of column with double quotes (add quotes around string)

Tags: mysql, concat

I have a table with a column that is TEXT type. In the column are numeric characters. What I'm trying to achieve is to wrap those characters in double quotes.

EXAMPLE:

```
NAME     ID     QTY
Apples   A1     1
Oranges  O1     1
Foo      F1     0
```

IDEAL OUTPUT:

```
NAME     ID     QTY
Apples   A1     "1"
Oranges  O1     "1"
Foo      F1     "0"
```

I attempted to run the following SELECT statement but it didn't give me the result I was expecting. Perhaps you can guide me in the right direction?

```
SELECT `qty`, CHAR('"'|| qty ||'"')
FROM `myTable`;
```

Thank You

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
SELECT NAME,ID,CONCAT('"',QTY,'"') QTY FROM `myTable`;
```

If you want single quotes, use the [**QUOTE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function

```
SELECT NAME,ID,QUOTE(QTY) QTY FROM `myTable`;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: The browser is hiding the slash but it should be:
SELECT NAME,ID,CONCAT('backslash"',QTY,'backslash"') QTY FROM `myTable`;